# Using $resource.query, I want to return an object that contains an array of the actual resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

By default, the `$resource.query()` is set up to expect an array of objects that become `$resource` objects.  To accommodate paging in a nice, restful way, I have my `GET /api/widgets` endpoint set up to return the following object:

```
{
  currentPage: 1,
  perPage: 20,
  totalItems: 10039,
  items: [{...}, {...}, {...}]
}
```

Is there a way to make it so that angular will know that the `items` property is the array of items to be `$resource` objects?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to specify your own custom action.

I imagine your code looks something like this:

```
factory('Widget', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/widgets');
});
```

Change it to this:

```
factory('Widget', function($resource) {
  return $resource(/api/widgets, null, {
    query: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: true,
      transformResponse: function(data) {
        return angular.fromJson(data).items;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: So, with this approach, how do I get access to the paging information from outside the transformResponse method?  You've definitely already answered the original question, but now I have a new problem :)

Comment: Not entirely sure, but you could try this `var widgets = Widget.query(); widgets.$promise.then(function(data) {console.log(data);});`.

Comment: So what I did, was set `isArray: false` and keep the shape of the returned object.  I iterated through `item in items` and just replaced them: `data.items[i] = new Widget(item);`  It works great!  I really appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 2):

the easy was is to use `$resouce.get`, if you wan to use query you can override that behaivor.

```
$resource('/notes/:id', null,
{
    'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:false}
});
```

more info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem.  The entire response object will be a `$resource`, and attempting to call `$save` or `$update` will attempt to persist values that aren't part of the the actual resource's model.  I need to configure `$resource.query()` to know that the actual resource objects are contained in the `items` array of the response.

Comment: I have done this, and works for me, I dont see how it wont work, when you call the update you will speciy the id and the new object, i dont see how it wont work `myresource.update({id:1}. { propery1: 1, property2: 2 })`

Comment: This will work if I'm using `$resource` strictly as a mechanism for constructing requests and getting a response object, however, there are additional features of `$resource` that aren't widely understood.  Specifically, the object(s) returned by a REST endpoints become `$resource` objects themselves.  In my case, I needed a way to tell angular that the `list` property of the returned object are the actual resources.  See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, and I wanted to propose a solution which could be a little better:

```
factory('Widget', function($resource) {
    return $resource(/api/widgets, null, {
        query: {
            interceptor: {
                response: function(response) {
                    return response.data.items;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think it may be better, because you are reusing the standard angular behaviour (which is, actually, doing a little more than `fromJson`) and intercepting the output result to filter what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use this pattern for query with paging informations.

```
module.config(function($resourceProvider){
    $resourceProvider.defaults.actions.query = {
        method: 'GET',
        interceptor: {
            response: function(response) {
                response.resource.$totalCount = response.data.totalCount;
                response.resource.$limit = response.data.limit;
                response.resource.$offset = response.data.offset;
                return response.resource;
            }
        },
        transformResponse: function(data, headers, status) {
            var out = angular.fromJson(data);
            out.data.totalCount = out.totalCount;
            out.data.limit = out.limit;
            out.data.offset = out.offset;
            return out.data;
        },
        isArray: true
    };
})
```